# Segmentation fault when trying to create a buffer of 100MB

Tags: c++

I am trying to write a large binary file into a buffer in a C++ program. GDB always gets a segfault after trying to create a buffer the same size as the file read. It either fails on fclose(pf), rewind, or f(open) which leads me to believe that there is something wrong when I am trying to create the buffer. My code segment is as follows.

```
static int fileTransfer(struct mg_connection *conn, char * filename){

    FILE *fp = fopen(filename, "r"); 

    fseek(fp, 0, SEEK_END);
    int size = ftell(fp);

    char buf[size];

    fclose(fp); 

    // This is an attempt to stop a segment fault from rewind. 
    fp = fopen(filename, "r"); 

    conn->connection_param = (void *) fp;
    size_t n = 0;

    if(fp != NULL)
    {
        n = fread(buf, 1, sizeof(buf), fp);

        mg_send_data(conn, buf, n);

        if(n < sizeof(buf) || conn->wsbits != 0)
        {
            fclose(fp);
            conn->connection_param = NULL;
        }
    }

return 1;
}
```

I have tried putting print statements in this code but they don't print to the console as they are running in a separate thread. Can someone give me some insight on why this segfault is happening, or some suggestions on how to make this code more efficient.

I should note that this code works properly on 1 and 10 MB files but not on anything larger.

Comment: allocating 100megs on the stack? youll get `document.location.hostname.substr(0,13)`. try to use `malloc`

Comment: Why was the `c++` tag changed`? This is legal c++ and called such in the question!

Comment: Also note that `fseek`, `fclose` and `fopen` don't always succeed.  Robust code should check for such errors.

Comment: Well, the dynamically sized arrays are an g++ extension, but still...

Comment: This code looks closer to C99, not C++.  VLAs aren't standard C++, and they use `struct type*`, `fseek()`, et al.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

never do this:

```
int size = ftell(fp);

char buf[size];
```

You are creating size on the STACK, not on the heap.... 100MB on the stack will not work.

AND... size must be a constant number, not a number coming from `ftell()`. I even don't know how it is compiling...

What you have to to is to allocate memory using `malloc()` or `new` operator.

```
static int fileTransfer(struct mg_connection *conn, char * filename){

    FILE *fp = fopen(filename, "r"); 

    fseek(fp, 0, SEEK_END);
    int size = ftell(fp);

    char * buf = new char[size];  // fix also here!

    fclose(fp); 

    // This is an attempt to stop a segment fault from rewind. 
    fp = fopen(filename, "r"); 

    conn->connection_param = (void *) fp;
    size_t n = 0;

    if(fp != NULL)
    {
        n = fread(buf, 1, size, fp); // fix also here!

        mg_send_data(conn, buf, n);

        if(n < size || conn->wsbits != 0)
        {
            fclose(fp);
            conn->connection_param = NULL;
        }
    }

    delete [] buf; // and you have to deallocate your buffer

    return 1;
}
```

Comment: You never delete buf - though that's OK in this instance as the OS will reclaim the memory this is a bad habit for people to get into unless they know what they are doing... probably bad practice on a site like SO.

Comment: Nevermind, you edited that a second before I posted the comment.

Comment: @WagnerPatriota Your solution worked, quick note on the ftell, it works because fseek reads to the end of the file to get the file size. If there is a better way to get the size of an opened file I am all for suggestions.

Comment: @JME Why couldn't you just have used `std::vector<size>`?  It is legal C++, as opposed to your usage of VLA.

Comment: the way to the get file size is correct. what is not correct is to put this value inside the `char buf[size]` because this one is created on the stack. in other words, this value is created in compile time. it should not even compile. if your size is a dynamic value [and you got it correctly] you MUST allocate memory dynamically. not on the stack in this case.

Comment: std::vector<size> is also a very good solution. But I think because he is still "learning", it's good to know what's behind the scenes... so it's always a good idea to get back to alloc()/free(), new/delete. ;-)

Comment: @WagnerPatriota - The beginner stage is the best time to learn how to write safe C++ code.  Using `new[]/delete[]` to create dynamic arrays is not necessary, as there are facilities in the library that do this, namely std::vector.  In addition, what if that function is updated to include functions that may throw an exception?  Then you can have a memory leak since that `delete[]` is never reached.

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie  OP's code is C code. There are no exceptions in C. Even in the above function, only the `new operator` can throw. If you swap it out for malloc, it cannot throw. It will simply return `NULL`. Even with new, if it throws, this code above won't leak because it wouldn't have allocated anything. Not before and not after. Only problem is that the file pointer won't be closed in the above if `new` throws.

Comment: @Brandon Then the subject tag should not be `C++` and instead should be changed to `C`.

Answer (score 2):

You are creating a buffer with automatic storage duration, which means it will be put on the stack by g++. The default stack size for any OS known to me is below 100 MB, meaning it will cause a segfault on system supporting them.

Try allocating your buffer with dynamic storage duration, which will place it on the heap.

Answer (score 2):

What's going on is actually the namesake of this site!  Basically, what is happening is your program is created it has a set amount of memory allocated for the stack.

When you create `char buf[size]`, you are using a C99 feature called a variable length array (VLA).  This allocates space on the stack for `buf`.  However, `buf` is too large for the stack, so your program fails.

In order to fix this problem, you should use `char * buf;` and then do `buf = malloc(size)`.  This will place buf on the heap, which is larger than the stack.  It also lets you check if you do not have enough memory, by checking if `malloc()` returns `NULL`.  You need to be sure to `free(buf)` before you exit though!

As a side note, you can check how much space you have on the stack by using the `ulimit -s` command.

Answer (score 2):

That seems like a lot to allocate on the stack. What if you put it on the heap instead?

```
char *buf = new char[size];
```

Answer (score 1):

Use `std::vector`.  Then you don't have the issues of stack space, or the other issue of writing non-standard C++ code:

```
#include <vector>
//...
static int fileTransfer(struct mg_connection *conn, char * filename)
{
    FILE *fp = fopen(filename, "r"); 
    fseek(fp, 0, SEEK_END);

    int size = ftell(fp);
    std::vector<char> buf(size);
    fclose(fp); 

    fp = fopen(filename, "r"); 

    conn->connection_param = (void *) fp;
    size_t n = 0;

    if(fp != NULL)
    {
        n = fread(&buf[0], 1, buf.size(), fp);
        mg_send_data(conn, &buf[0], n);
        if(n < buf.size() || conn->wsbits != 0)
        {
            fclose(fp);
            conn->connection_param = NULL;
        }
    }
    return 1;
}
```